# How to generate Excel chart from Excel template?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, template-engine

1. I have data in 10 columns in Excel sheet
2. I created an Excel template with 2 columns (salary, average) and a graph generated by those 2 columns
3. I need to take that Excel template as input and the out put should be

An Excel sheet with 2 columns of DATA and a CHART or GRAPH generated by that data.

Comment: Take a look at my blog post: [NPOI with Excel Table and dynamic Chart](http://www.leniel.net/2009/10/npoi-with-excel-table-and-dynamic-chart.html)

Comment: Can be closed as either off-topic (Super User) or Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a template excel sheet and save it as as xml (save as => choose excel 2003 xml format). Now you just have to replace your template values with placeholders which can easily be replaced using string replacements.

We just created an excel import/export this way. Be careful though, excel does not read all xml files, even if they are valid xml. When writing relay on string operations instead of linq to xml or xml writers and stick **exactly** to the format excel creates when saving.